# How to get callback events from Native platform to dart code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm creating a plugin for downloading files from the server, for this, I'm downloading files on the Android side and want to give callback events to the flutter side like start downloading, in-progress, and download completed.

And for this plugin, I have used Pigeon(pigeon: ^0.1.17) library to generate code. which is using `BasicMessageChannel` for communication,

So How could I get callback events from Android to the flutter side?

Do I need to implement A separate MethodChannel to listen to events?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep listening to a series of events, I think it's better to use a `EventChannel` instead of `MethodChannel`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html